# Getting dependency artifacts in a Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm trying to write a Maven plugin somewhat similar to the well-known `exec:java` mojo. It creates a class loader, loads the project's artifacts into Maven's JVM, and does something with them. Here's my code to create the class loader:

```
Set<URL> urls = new HashSet<URL>();
try {
    for (Object artifactObject : project.getCompileArtifacts()) {
        Artifact artifact = (Artifact) artifactObject;
        urls.add(artifact.getFile().toURI().toURL());
    }
    urls.add(project.getArtifact().getFile().toURI().toURL());
} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex); // this really shouldn't happen
}
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls.toArray(new URL[urls.size()]));
```

According to the scant documentation I could find, and the source code for `exec:java`, `project.getCompileArtifacts()` should return the direct and indirect dependencies with compile scope. But it is returning an empty list. What's up?